# How to replace the deprecated setOnUtteranceCompletedListener

Tags: android, text-to-speech, deprecated

I have this code

```
 else {
            int listenerResult = tts
                    .setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(new OnUtteranceCompletedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onUtteranceCompleted(String utteranceId) {
                            callWithResult.onDone(utteranceId);
                        }
                    });
            if (listenerResult != TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                Log.e(TAG, "failed to add utterance completed listener");
            }
        }
```

Unfortunately since API 18 `setOnUtteranceCompletedListener` has been deprecated.

Android Developer site say to replace with `UtteranceProgressListener`, but I haven't understand how should I edit my code mantaining the same behaviour.

Comment: This is the first result in Google, but has been rendered useless because Simon, ozbek, Corey Ogburn, and Frank van Puffelen marked it as a duplicate without citing how the original question answers this one. Thanks for the added hassle of having to read an unrelated question to find it indirectly resolves the issue.